# Self-signed certificates and HTTPS Error

Tags: ssl

1. I'm creating a Certificate Authority with openssl, and signing my server & client certificate with it (they both are the same).
2. Installing CA as a Trusted Root CA and Intermediate CA, server certificate - as a Personal one.
3. Adding server certificate in IIS6, adding bindings - and getting the right https connection via browser on server side.

But on the client side -

1. Installing CA as a Trusted Root CA and Intermediate CA, client certificate as Personal, server certificate as External.
2. Checking all the certificates - they are in a working state, CA is connected to client, everything looks normal.
3. Trying to get via Chrome - I'm getting the connection, but it is unsecured (can't connect to https). (But I still can connect Chrome, and use all the requests in Google Rest Client.)
4. In IE I'm getting `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`.

What am I doing wrong here?

SOLVED. Had the same `serial_number` for both client and server certificates

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. Had the same serial_number for both client and server certificates